# express-validator, validationErrors is an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I want to check if a string is an email. This is the code.

```
req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email address').isEmail();
var validationErrors = req.validationErrors();

if(validationErrors) {
    console.log(`Validation errors ${validationErrors}`);
}
```

console output:

```
Validation errors [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) feature of ES6. It can embed variables in string like you did. But it doesn't parse `object` and `array`. Use traditional `console.log`:

```
console.log('Validation errors ', validationErrors);
```

PS: Use `console.error` to log errors, instead of `console.log`.

Comment: Thank you it's working. Any idea of how to show it up on pug?
I made this
`if validationErrors
     h1= validationErrors
`

Comment: @AlessandroBertozzi I don't understand what you're asking. Can you explain bit more? If you have code snippet, add it to your question for better formatting.

Comment: No problem, I figured out how to do that. Thank you for the answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you use RegEx,
just put this code into your function

```
var checkMail = /^[\w\.]+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;

alert(checkMail.test('dasdasd@gmail.com'));
```

Comment: For the moment I'm trying with express-validator